# Some URL is missing on referral channel on Google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

How can i fix this (/) in referral path?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8N1KI.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass document.referrer as custom dimension (hit level). Then you can see this information more reliably.